# Cant fine id tag in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I want to change some div background color in my word press web site , I can find css id in inspect element and  change the color but i can't find css id in css style sheet . 
`http://pajohantest.ir/` is my web site and i want to change the upper black area color.
+
when i change this tag `background color` : 
inspect element

```
  media="all"
  #masthead, #homepage-message, #footer-sidebar, article .entry-format, blockquote, pre {
    background-color: #111;
  }
```

and this is the masthead tag in scc style sheet and there is no background option to change

```
#masthead .breadcrumb {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
```

Comment: Please post some screen shot or the URL and which Div you wanna manipulate so we can understand the exact issue

Comment: Depending on your browser, the inspector should tell you where exactly in your CSS the code is (especially true in WordPress where CSS is static). In any case please post more information so we can further understand the problem.

Comment: Don't edit the theme directly, your changes will be overwritten when you update the theme. [Create a child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and define your color there.

Comment: edited OP . sorry guys it is my first time that i post a question :D

Comment: edited again . its my first time .

Comment: An extra hint: Do some Research about cache control! your files are not getting cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background-color` property is set in Line 40 of you dark.css File. Its set for the  `<header id="masthead" role="banner">` Tag )

Comment: where can I find dark.css file?